# MySql How to get records to show in chat conversation list

Tags: mysql, sql

I've single chat table as shown in the image. I want to group the chat listing like in facebook style.[image: Table after selecting the conversations of user 2]

Here user 2 is logged in and his conversations are selected using

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `chat`  `t` 
WHERE  `from` =2
OR  `to` =2
ORDER BY sent DESC
```

But here I want the latest single entry between 2 and any other user. Where 2 can be in either from or to column. As a final result it should return 2 entries with id 25 and 17 respectively.

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * , (
r.from + r.to
) AS dist
FROM (

SELECT * 
FROM  `cometchat` t
WHERE (
t.from =2
OR t.to =2
)
ORDER BY t.sent DESC
)r
GROUP BY dist
ORDER BY r.sent DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `chat`  `t` 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(s.id) FROM chat s WHERE s.`from` =2
OR  s.`to` =2 GROUP BY (IF(s.`from`=2, s.`to`, s.`from`)))
ORDER BY sent DESC
```